# Finite groups with no common prime factor of their orders

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be finite groups s.t. their orders have no common prime factor, and let $\phi: G\rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism. I want to show that $\phi(g)=e \space \forall g \in G$ where $e$ is the identity element of the group.

I know that since $|G| < \infty$ and $|H|<\infty$, $|G|=|ker\phi||im\phi|$. I do not see how to proceed from here. Perhaps by using Lagrange's theorem, but H is not necessarily a subgroup of G.

Comment: $\operatorname{im}\phi$ is a subgroup of $H$, hence ...?

Comment: So, $|im\phi|$ divides $|H|$ $\Rightarrow$ $|im\phi|=e$ and $|im\phi|$ divides $|G|$, so $\phi(g)=e$ $\forall g\in G$. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: You need to explain why the fact that $\lvert \operatorname{im}\phi\rvert$ divides both, $\lvert G\rvert$ and $\lvert H\rvert$, implies $\lvert \operatorname{im}\phi\rvert = 1$.

Comment: The identity element is the only element that will satisfy those conditions. I thought that was rather trivial, but if there is something more subtle I am missing I'd appreciate you pointing it out.

Comment: What does "The identity element is the only element that will satisfy those conditions" mean? $\lvert \operatorname{im}\phi\rvert$ is a positive integer, the number of elements of the subgroup $\operatorname{im}\phi$. It is fairly trivial that that must be $1$, but you need to (be able to) say why.

Comment: I am guessing it is because of the one fact I have not used, that the orders have no common prime factor. This implies $e$ is the only element in the image of $\phi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x\in G$ we have that the order of $\phi(x)$ divides the order of $H$. Also $\phi(1)=\phi(x^{|G|})=\phi(x)^{|G|}=1$ so that the order of $\phi(x)$ also divides the order of $G$ whence the order is $1$ and $\phi(x)=1$.